# Drupal views require_once

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to add some sanity to the chaos that is Drupal by separating files in a fo-MVC structure.  Within a Drupal view you can add Header or Footer code in textarea boxes with the option to add "PHP Code".  Here is my code within the Header textarea box:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: 
Failed opening required '<path_to_root>/sites/all/modules/citysensei/controllers/staff_index.php'
(include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php') in <path_to_root>/includes/common.inc(1355) : 
eval()'d code on line 2
```

Is there a work around for this?

Thanks in advance,

Kris (quickly giving up on Drupal)

CODE:

```
require_once('<path_to_root>/sites/all/modules/citysensei/controllers/staff_index.php');
```

Comment: Sorry, faux(fake) MVC(Model View Controller design pattern).
Because Drupal doesn't allow you to do anything but what its setup to do. Organic my ass.

Comment: Where is your code i only see trace info ?

Comment: It sounds like you are not really using Drupal fully, Rather than trying together something that works with views, maby re post your question asking your full intent and see if you get a good answer. Your question kind of reads "My spoon is broken I can't open a tin can with it, can you fix my spoon" There is a huge powerful theaming layer in Drupal which could almost defiantly do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will solve your particular problem or not but Drupal encourages you to use their custom include function, like this in your case:

```
module_load_include('php', 'citysensei', 'controllers/staff_index');
```

This way a user can download your module and stick it whereever they like inside a modules directory and your code will still work.